# VBA Set Dropdown value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that I have written in excel and I have navigated to a webpage using "ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink", which works just as I need it!

However, I now need to update a dropdown menu on that webpage.

I have an ID for the dropdown and each selection obviously has a value.  I want to set the selected option using the value, which I have in the excel sheet.

I am struggling because I don't know how to access elements on the page, once opened using .FollowHyperlink.

After .FollowHyperlink is the webpage then active, is there something like ActiveWebPage.getElementById?

Appreciate any help.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is use com automation to call an instance of internet explorer and navigate to the page in question, this will give you the document model, from there you can do most anything, see [IE (Internet Explorer) Automation using Excel VBA](http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml)

Sample VBA follows

```
Private Sub IE_Autiomation()
Dim i As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = False

IE.Navigate "http://www.excely.com/"

' Statusbar
Application.StatusBar = "www.excely.com is loading. Please wait..."

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

' Find 2 input tags:
'   1. Text field
'   <input type="text" class="textfield" name="s" size="24" value="" />
'
'   2. Button
'   <input type="submit" class="button" value="" />

Application.StatusBar = "Search form submission. Please wait..."

Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Name = "s" Then

        ' Set text for search
        objCollection(i).Value = "excel vba"

    Else
        If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" And _
           objCollection(i).Name = "" Then

            ' "Search" button is found
            Set objElement = objCollection(i)

        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
objElement.Click    ' click button to search

' Wait while IE re-loading...
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

' Show IE
IE.Visible = True

' Clean up
Set IE = Nothing
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```